# Can we add Stack Overflow teams to our list of communities?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, top-bar, stack-overflow-for-teams

I am a member of a [private team](https://stackoverflow.com/teams). I would like to add a link to that team in my list of communities, here:

[image: "Your Communities" list screenshot]

Right now it doesn't look like this is an option. I have to go to Stack Overflow to find my list of teams.

---

This same question has been asked on Meta Stack Overflow: [Could it be made possible to add Teams to the "Your communities" list?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/368376/5560474)

However, because the "your communities" list is present across the Stack Exchange network, I believe the question is on-topic here (at the very least, closing this question as duplicate of that MSE question would help point users there -- but since that question doesn't have an answer either, it would be nice to see some interaction).

Comment: Team question is on-topic on  https://meta.stackoverflow.com/ not here.

Comment: eh, i would assume that if you wanted it to show up in your list of communities, you'd want it to show in your list of communities everywhere, not just on SO

Comment: @user400654 as it is a question specific to SO for Teams, as that is really what needs to be adapted, it is ontopic on MSO. Teams has a seperate team of software engineers that tackle problems directly related to teams.

Comment: @Luuklag I'm asking for a feature update to SE (the your communities list) that would link me to teams. It's an inbound link for teams, so don't think they'd actually have to do anything?

Comment: @Shree technically the top bar is on topic here - and well, to some extent, having easier access to a team would be awesome for a lot of us non SO users who're using teams for various network related actvities. I think it should stay :D

Comment: @JourneymanGeek you know better than me. I appreciate your comment.

Comment: The question specifically says "I have to go to Stack Overflow to find my list of teams."  - which signals to me that this question is about the network, not SO.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We don't have any plans to make Teams accessible in the site selector dropdown as you're asking here *but* as of today we've made teams accessible nearly network-wide (excluding MathOverflow and the International SO sites) in the left navigation so I hope this solves your request and makes it easier for you to find your Teams.

Speaking for myself, this is a change I've been hoping to have since Teams first launched and I'm really glad to have the unified experience network-wide since I'm on many Teams and am rarely on Stack Overflow proper.

I'm not completely certain whether to mark this as [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined) or [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) - I think that, while we're declining your specific request, the solution we've built solves the issue mentioned in the question, making it completed.

Comment: Agreed -- this solves my problem, just not in the way I envisioned!

Comment: I see SO for Teams sidebar on International SO sites.

Comment: (Note: subsequent changes have made this no longer true at present. See this Q&A for more details: [Is Stack Overflow for Teams going to be removed from the sidebar on the rest of the network?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/383092/335251))