# Is Stack Overflow for Teams going to be removed from the sidebar on the rest of the network?

Tags: support, sidebar, stack-overflow-for-teams

[image: Screenshot of notification - Says "Stack Overflow for Teams is moving to its own domain! When the migration is complete, you will access your Teams at stackoverflowteams.com, and they will no longer appear in the left sidebar for stackoverflow.com. Check your email for updates"]

I got a toast on my left sidebar saying -

> "Stack Overflow for Teams is moving to its own domain! When the migration is complete, you will access your Teams at *stackoverflowteams.com*, and they will no longer appear in the left sidebar on *stackoverflow.com*.
>
> Check your email for updates."

I checked my mail and this was mentioned:

> You will be able to access your private team from stackoverflowteams.com. Private teams will no longer appear in the left sidebar on stackoverflow.com and will not be accessible from the public site.

Is this true for the rest of the network as well? I actually tend to check Teams from MSE and SU. This would result in a *minor* rejigging of my tabs but I can imagine this could change the workflow for some.

Comment: Teams questions should be asked at Meta Stack Overflow.

Comment: @bad_coder Not when they relate to the entire network. It's in the tag description.

Comment: @Catija I wasn't aware teams could integrate with sites besides SO proper.

Comment: It's in the sidebar network-wide and that seems to be what the question is about specifically, @bad_coder . :)

Comment: [I'm well aware of the appropriate place to ask](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/362494/should-stack-overflow-for-teams-be-on-topic-on-meta-se)  and the question is about the sidebar network wide. Once the current set of flaming chainsaws I am juggling vis a vis notifications and the new inbox are taken care of - I'm debating asking for some sidebar changes. I have a broader plan, and am quite aware where to post

Comment: For those who wanna know more about the change, read [*What does Teams getting its own domain mean practically?*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/420980) in MSO and an [article](https://stackoverflow.help/en/articles/6649858-teams-domain-migration-user-guide) from SO.help.

Comment: I'm curious to know: The popup is shown to which users? Is it only shown to those who currently have a *Team*?

Comment: I think it's phased through teams. I am on two teams via SE and only got the email for one. I assume people will get the popup in 6-8 weeks or parts thereof

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, it applies network-wide. Once your team has been migrated to stackoverflowteams.com it will no longer appear in the sidebar anywhere on the network.

Comment: What about the remaining stuff like "Companies", "Collectives"? Will they too be removed in the near future?

Comment: @RandomPerson No, those will remain as they are.

Comment: Why is it being removed? It can change domains while still being left in the sidebar.

Comment: Will we still have the "Create free Team" on the side bar of every site? Or is this also going away?

Comment: Will the older but more symmetrical layout return? Or has this nothing to do with the left navigation panel? Will the left panel disappear for users who have not enabled it once?   

Comment: @curiousdannii Other planned changes make it infeasible to still display in the sidebar, as the public sites will no longer be able to access that information. We don't have details to share about that right now, but grouping the "very visible" changes into one swap makes for a better transition experience, rather than removing them from the sidebar later as a separate change.

Comment: @ShadowTheKidWizard As far as I know, the Create free Team banner will still be there. I'm not familiar with what Teams-related things will still be present moving forward, only that the list of your teams is disappearing.

Comment: @Mari-LouAСлаваУкраїні This change isn't any kind of move to get rid of the left sidebar and nothing regarding the sidebar itself will change.

Comment: I would guess that the change is to make the Teams infrastructure completely seperate from the public network, so that security issues affecting the public network can't affect Teams. It would also mean that external auditors would be able to assess Teams security without also needing to assess the public network. Maybe Teams is going to become fedramp/hipaa/whatever compliant in the future?

Comment: Related (with a touch more information about why we cannot pull Teams info into the broader network moving forward): [Why is the removal of Teams from stackoverflow.com necessitating the removal of all ties?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421496/why-is-the-removal-of-teams-from-stackoverflow-com-necessitating-the-removal-of)

Answer (score -1):

It seems that stackoverflow.com can't [*know*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421496/3648282) about your Teams but no such restriction applies on the stackoverflowteams.com site itself, where all your teams appear in the site chooser.

[image]

This certainly is an inconvenient change.

There are [many](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/299366/282094) domains with knowledge of [other domains](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/248453/282094) that don't fall under the Stackoverflow.com subdomain list. The reason offered is for [SOC 2](https://us.aicpa.org/interestareas/frc/assuranceadvisoryservices/aicpasoc2report) compliance when reviewed by an auditor, but such [doesn't require](https://www.mossadams.com/articles/2021/07/soc-2-trust-services-criteria) this inconvenience; indeed factors allowed for are: "meeting the entity’s objectives" and "allowing information to flow up, down, and across the organization".

Rather than being a "technical difficulty", it's more of a limitation built into the design and language of the organization's requirements. Rather than writing a slightly more lenient criteria requirement they have produced one which is not necessary to comply with SOC 2; necessitating the removal of the teams from the site chooser. Such teething pains were often built in to documents specifying implementations of the Common Criteria in various organizations.