# Why are there no private communities?

Tags: feature-request

Why doesn't Stack Exchange allow users to create private sites or communities?

Comment: Um...it does? https://stackoverflowteams.com/

Comment: I don't think we should close questions as duplicates of their answers.

Answer (score 6):

Stack Overflow has this feature, but it is part of the [Stack Overflow for Teams](https://stackoverflowteams.com/) program, allowing teams to create private communities. If you are interested, you can create a team for free.

Unfortunately, this feature is not currently available on other Stack Exchange sites.

Comment: Is there a point to having a Stack Overflow for Teams for other Stack Exchange sites? I mean, can't you do whatever you need with Stack Overflow for Teams?

Comment: Good point. Even better username.

Comment: Its also worth noting that [stackoverflow for teams is going to its own domain](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/383092/is-stack-overflow-for-teams-going-to-be-removed-from-the-sidebar-on-the-rest-of) and is dis.. I mean deintegrating from Stack Overflow proper