# What's the plan for keeping the moderator Teams instance visible enough to stay useful?

Tags: feature-request, moderator-tools, moderators, stack-overflow-for-teams

Teams moved. They're going to be completely separated from the actual SE sites. So that means there are no links to them on SE sites, and especially no inbox or notifications about stuff happening in Teams on the SE network.

There are reasons for this, and those reasons apply mostly to Teams handling sensitive information from big to huge companies. For the moderator Teams instance this change is close to a death sentence. This will dramatically reduce the visibility of the Team, and likely will reduce traffic a lot.

SE has been talking about certifications like SOC2 and ISO when justifying these changes. But apart from that they haven't been very specific about the reasoning behind this redesign. This makes it hard to suggest what to do because we have no idea what would be acceptable for SE.

The absolute minimum to keep the moderator Team useful would be a link in the sidebar to it. Just to remind us that it exists, and that we maybe should check in at times to see if anything interesting was posted there. This would be pretty easy to implement, and would not cause any issues with the certifications SE is seeking.

Better would be to add an integration for the inbox and new posts/updates. This would affect the certifications as information would have to flow from the Team to the SE network. But as Teams has a Slack integration there must be a way to do this in a reasonably secure manner. So SE could use the same method to add a kind of plugin for Teams that would connect a Teams instance to the SE network.

I can't really give all that much constructive feedback here as I simply don't know the limitations of what would be possible. But the current state is likely to render the moderator Teams instance mostly useless.

Comment: A little while ago I wrote a userscript to add SO Teams (and any other custom links) into the left sidebar ( https://stackapps.com/q/9582/92477 ). The userscript has to be manually added, of course, but it may be handy. Feel free to delete this comment if it is overly-promotional, although I feel it is relevant here

Comment: Similar question: [Is Stack Overflow for Teams going to be removed from the sidebar on the rest of the network?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/383092/282094)

Comment: @cocomac we can't have enough promotion of [Stack Apps](https://stackapps.com/). When it isn't full of placeholders, it is an awesome resource for apps and scripts to make the SE experience better.

Comment: Go put the placeholders on a different page then @rene, your a mod after all ;)

Comment: There's still a direct link to the Mods Teams on the diamond inbox, but I agree that I've never thought of opening that inbox to access the Teams.